# The generalized Euler's function in number field for ideal $\mathfrak{a}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Is there any results about the Euler's totient function for ideals?

---

> More precisely, for any number field $k,$ if we define $\phi(\mathfrak{a})$ as the number of residue classes $\bar{\mathfrak{a}}\in\mathfrak{o}_k/\mathfrak{a}$ such that gcd$(\bar{\mathfrak{a}},\mathfrak{a})=\mathfrak o_k$. Then is the fuction $\phi(\mathfrak{a})$ sharing the basic properties that the usual Euler 's totient function has?
>
> For example, for all $\alpha\in\mathfrak{o}_k$ prime to $\mathfrak{a}$ we have
> $$\alpha^{\phi(\mathfrak{a})}\equiv1\mod\mathfrak{a};$$
> for any prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ and for any $\alpha\in\mathfrak{o}_k$
> $$\alpha^{\phi(\mathfrak{p})}\equiv\alpha\mod\mathfrak{p}$$
> and $$\phi(\mathfrak{a})=N(\mathfrak{a})\prod_{\mathfrak{p}|\mathfrak{a}}\left(1-\frac{1}{N\mathfrak{p}}\right).$$

Any comment will be acknowledged!

Comment: You're letting $\phi(\mathfrak a)$ be the size $(\mathfrak o_k/\mathfrak a)^*$. The first two properties are then basic facts about groups, right?

Comment: Yes, I see it, @Dylan, then the last one is obvious.

Comment: Hi, do you have any references for this problem? I heard there was some research on it.

Comment: Hi! Can someone please explain why the last one is obvious? I am having trouble seeing it.